# Hibernate Lazy using Initilize or EAGER loading

Tags: hibernate

I have three tables,

```
users
user_associations
association_type.
```

Users are associated to each other through the users_associations table and then the association is given a type such as PARENT, or FRIEND, etc..

When I call my view I have the table data for user's associations to each other. Within each list there is a relationship to the current users data, the associated users data, and the list of association types.

I am using Hibernate and I am confused between EAGER fetching the data and LAZY loading it. When I call my DAO it looks like this

```
List<UsersAssoc> assoc = (List<UsersAssoc>)session.getNamedQuery("UsersAssoc.getAssoc").setInteger("id", id).list();
```

To get LAZY loading to work I have to call Hibernate.initialize on all of the sub objects

```
    for(UserAssoc a : assoc ) {
           Hibernate.initialize(a.getUser() );
           Hibernate.initialize(a.getAssocTypes() );
           Hibernate.initialize(a.getAssociatedUser() );
    }
```

I need to refer to all of the data in my view and I am trying to do it without storing all of it in memory. Which option is the best? Eagerly load it or Initialize each type within Hibernate. This might not even be the right way of doing it. I need some direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

lazy describes whether collections are loaded immediately -- so if you have lazy=false hibernate will by default load the collection when you load the parent.  It is a mapping attribute.

when using hql, your fetching strategy overrides the setting in your mapping.  From the documentation:

"A "fetch" join allows associations or collections of values to be initialized along with their parent objects using a single select. This is particularly useful in the case of a collection. It effectively overrides the outer join and lazy declarations of the mapping file for associations and collections. See Section 19.1, “Fetching strategies” for more information."

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

It is common to have all your mapping be lazy false, but to have specialized hql based DAO methods so you can get at your data in specific ways for specific cases.

Comment: So in my case calling Hibernate.initialize on everything is doing the same thing as just EAGERLY loading it? @hvgotcodes

Comment: @johnnyQuestisasellout not exactly.  they are basically different ways of bypassing the mapping...when you do an eager fetch i believe the default way is to do a join to get the children.  with initialize im not sure how it works.  it might be the same.

Comment: But does calling Hibernate.initialize() not actually load the data into memory until its called? I am confused as to if EAGERLY loading it is using more memory than calling Hibernate.initalize() on each object that has the potential to being used. @hvgotcodes

Comment: @johnny in both cases, the end result is all the children are loaded and on the session, so they are all in memory.  It is ok to load objects, so dont worry about it too much.  worry if you are loading hundreds of objects or profiling shows each query taking a ridiculous amount of memory